# Updating one table from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I have created a new table for my use , lets say t1 which has 8 columns in it. I have populated 3 columns through a procedure. Column 1 is name. Now I want to populate the 4th column for corresponding name. This would be update with where clause.

The scenario is I have created a query which has the result, calling that t2 which has name and total_amount. Now I want to populate total_amount into the 4th column of t1.

The approach that I'm right now following is looping through each name in t1 and finding its counter total_amount in t2(with clause) and updating the value in t1. But it is taking infinite time. First is because of looping in t1 , secondly the t2 is itself a query which is executing again and again.

Now, the actual task is much more complicated and I have just provided the crux of it. Please suggest me an approach which is fast.

```
create or replace procedure proc
is

temp_value number(18,2);

CURSOR total is
select name, age, sex from data_table where
{conditions};

/*Gives me name and age in 1st and 2nd column and likewise data in 3rd column */

begin

FOR temp IN total LOOP

    with aa as (SELECT b.name,
         NVL (SUM (c.amount), 0) as total_amount
    FROM data_table2 b, data_table3 c
   WHERE     {joins and groub by}
   )
   /* This gives me total amount for corresponding name. There is no repetition of name */

   select nvl(sum(total_amount),0) into temp_value from aa where name = temp.name;

    update t1 set amount = temp_value where name = temp.name;

    END LOOP;

END;
/
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL, MS SQL Server or Oracle here? Don't tag products not involved...

Comment: can you represent your tables in schema?

Comment: @jarlh I'm using Oracle here. Sorry for the tags

Comment: @anatol I have now given the code. May be it will give a better idea

Comment: @jarlh Have a look now.. Hope it gives a better understanding now

Comment: Couple of examples of correlated update in Oracle here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640851/oracle-sql-correlated-update This is what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Cant add a comment to question, hence putting it here.

Per your example:

```
    with aa as (SELECT b.name,
     NVL (SUM (c.amount), 0) as total_amount
FROM data_table2 b, data_table3 c
WHERE     {joins and groub by}
)
/* This gives me total amount for corresponding name. There is no repetition of name */

select nvl(sum(total_amount),0) into temp_value from aa where name = temp.name;

update t1 set amount = temp_value where name = temp.name;
```

In your with clause you you take some sum, and then populate the sum of those sum for all names in your cursor. Why cant you directly do:

```
    SELECT SUM(NVL(total_amount, 0)) INTO temp_vale FROM
       data_tabl1, data_tabl2, data_tabl3
       WHERE
        --JOIN CONDITIONS
      AND data_tabl1.total)name = --data_tabl2/3.name
    GROUP BY --clause;
```

Why I say this is, with clause is not always a good idea. If your 'with' has a huge data, then it will run forever. 'With' is used to take care of repetitive tables with small data being joined again and again.

Also for tuning purpose, try some hints.

Also, NVL(SUM..) why not SUM(NVL(total_amount, 0))?