# copy one column data from result set to a column in another table , in oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I want to update a column in table A (100 row within 5000 row) with 100 row of a column in another table, randomly . some thing like this(but in a loop for 100 records):

```
  update kc7crdtfile 
     set kc7crdtfile.k7748crid = (select y.k7749crid from KC7CTBURQ y where rownum<100)
   where kc7crdtfile.k7749crid IS NULL
     AND kc7crdtfile.k7732sts in (5, 6, 7, 9, 12)
```

Comment: Your update will throw error: Single row subquery returns multiple rows. What joins or identifies the 100 rows from table A with the other table? In other words, what is the matching column between kc7crdtfile and KC7CTBURQ?

Comment: Each `k7748crid` can only have one value, not 99 values. You have to specify which value you want your `update` to choose.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a column linking the two tables other than `k7748crid`, you could use a correlated update.  Refer : [**Example**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15640851/oracle-sql-correlated-update)

Running a single update using the above would be efficient for large records than a loop.But, since you expect only 100 rows to be updated, you may also use an implicit `cursor loop` by filtering out the updated values using `ROWNUM = 1` .This would work even if there is no linking column between the two tables other than `k7749crid`.

```
BEGIN
   FOR rec IN (SELECT y.k7749crid
                 FROM KC7CTBURQ y
                WHERE ROWNUM <= 100)
   LOOP
      UPDATE kc7crdtfile k
         SET k.k7748crid = rec.k7749crid
       WHERE     k.k7749crid IS NULL
             AND k.k7732sts IN (5,
                                6,
                                7,
                                9,
                                12)
             AND NOT EXISTS
                    (SELECT 1
                       FROM kc7crdtfile k2
                      WHERE     k2.k7748crid = k.k7748crid
                            AND k2.k7749crid IS NULL
                            AND k2.k7732sts IN (5,
                                                6,
                                                7,
                                                9,
                                                12))
             AND ROWNUM = 1;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```